# Numpy add a matrix to slices of another matrix

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

Lets say I have a matrix `X (1000x10)` and a matrix `Y (20x10)`. I want to efficiently add `Y` to every `(20x10)` block of `X` repeatedly (therefore 50 blocks). Is there an efficient way to do this with numpy? I don't want to use `np.repeat` as the original matrices are huge and I want to prevent unnecessary duplication of `Y`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can leverage [argument list unpacking](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists), [NumPy broadcasting](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) and [the fact that `ndarray.reshape()` returns a view](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html) to perform the operation:

```
tmp = X.reshape(-1, *Y.shape)
tmp += Y
```

No additional data will be allocated and after these operations, `X` will contain the result of the operation.

Comment: The difference is that calculating `X.reshape() + Y` allocates and creates a new array, while `tmp += Y` modifies the already allocated values. No additional RAM is allocated. And the output is in the correct shape, as `X` never changes its shape.

Comment: Wow! this looks magic to me! how does it work? can you explain what is `*Y.shape`? and why `X.reshape(-1, *Y.shape)` does not copy `X` to `tmp`? (is it like reference to `X`)? Thank you!

Comment: `X.reshape()` doesn't copy the data but merely creates a view (reference) on the original data. So when you modify data in `tmp`, you will see the change in `X` and vice versa. Secondly, in your case running [`X.reshape(-1, *Y.shape)` is the same as running `X.reshape(-1, 20, 10)`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists). Additionally, [a `-1` will make numpy infer the size of that dimension](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html), in your case it is the same as running `X.reshape(50, 20, 10)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `np.tile` to "expand" (more accurately, tile) the smaller array to match the size of the larger array, for example

```
x = np.zeros([1000,10])
y = np.ones([20,10])
new_x = x + np.tile(y,(50,1))
```

This will create a temporary large array in-memory to add to `x` but is immediately thrown away, so it depends on your memory capacity and the size of the array, but I believe it's the most efficient there is in terms of CPU usage and readability.

The other option is to of course loop over the larger array and broadcast the smaller array to every piece of it (50 times in this case) but it will be more time consuming and less efficient in terms of CPU, but will be lighter on memory.

An example of the 2nd option:

```
for i in range(0,len(x),20):
    x[i:i+20,:] = y
```